# How can I detect that my code is running through the Django shell?

Tags: django

In some cases, we do manual cleanup for our app via the Django shell (`python manage.py shell`). Of course this should be done with care but in this particular internal app it's just the most effective way to do the work.

When running in the Django shell, I'd like to disable some behavior that otherwise would be triggered.

How do I detect that my code is running through the shell?

I'm imagining something like:

```
if not django.SHELL:
    # Don't notify chat when running from the shell
    notifications.send(dev_user, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a different settings file and include a flag in that that you can determine, then you can use `manage.py`'s [`--setting`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/) flag to use that settings file

Add a setting in a new settings file to override and include one in your normal settings file that defaults to true

```
SEND_NOTIFICATIONS = False
```

In code

```
from django.conf import settings
if not settings.SEND_NOTIFICATIONS:
```

Call the shell with the correct settings file

```
python manage.py shell --settings=settings.my_override
```